# Ubuntu 16.04 detects GEOS 3.5.1, but I installed 3.7.2 from source. How do I fix it?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

When doing geos-config --version, it comes back 3.5.1

But I built 3.7.2 by source following [These Instructions](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu#GEOS)and it exists in ~/geos-3.7.2 directory.

I'm super new to Ubuntu, so not sure where to start.

Comment: If you type `which geos-config` what do you get? I will guess that your have 3.5.1 installed some other place - and that place is in your PATH.

Comment: @SorenA, I get /usr/local/bin/geos-config

Comment: so you have an old 3.5.1 version installed in /use/local/bin, and a newer 3.7.2 in your home, dir ~/geos-3.7.2. ...

Comment: Yeah, I got 3.5.1 from ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable  and built 3.7.2 from source. So I don't know how to remove the 3.5.1

Comment: I removed all libraries of GEOS and installed the source.  The version now says 3.7.2, but when I run an api, I get the warning that there's a different compile-time and runtime version for GEOS